# Determine the appropriate HTTP method in a reusable function for API requests using Angular's HTTPClient

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, request, angular-httpclient

I want to implement a reusable service for making requests to my API.

Right now, I have it working as intended, but for `GET` requests only.

Here's the function:

```
  makeAPIRequest = ({ ...opts }) => {
    return this.http.get(opts.url, opts.params)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response)
      .catch(err => this.handleError(err));
  };
```

And here's an example of how it's being used:

```
  getCustomer(id): Promise<Customer> {
    return this.APIService.makeAPIRequest({
      url: this.customerEditUrl(id)
    }) as Promise<Customer>;
  }
```

I want to extend the functionality such that I'm able to pass an HTTP method into `opts`, but I'm not sure how to do that cleanly. I'd like to avoid using a large conditional and repeating myself -- it'd be nice to be able to approach this concisely. For example, if I pass in `opts` that look like this:

```
 { url: this.customerEditUrl(id), params, httpMethod: 'POST' }
```

How can I make my `makeAPIRequest` function look like this?

```
  makeAPIRequest = ({ ...opts }) => {
    return this.http.post(opts.url, opts.params)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response)
      .catch(err => this.handleError(err));
  };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did this help or do you need any more info?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `this.http.post()` you could manually create a new request. The request constructor allows specifying the method as a string.

Have a look at: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#request

One of the constructor overloads for `this.http.request(...)` looks as follows:

```
request(method: string, url: string, options: { body?: any; headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType: "blob"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<Blob>
```

As you can see the first parameter is the HTTP Method as string. The rest should be relatively familiar to you.

```
this.http.request(opts.httpMethod, opts.url, opts.params)
```

should do the trick ;)

---

I also suggest you have a look at using observable directly instead of converting the returned observable to a promise.